# Does oracle supports stftime() function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query where i have to use strftime() function in oracle doc it says it supports https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13203_01/tuxedo/tux80/atmi/rf3c22.html strftime when i try use in query it is  throwing exception

exception:
ORA-00904: "STRFTIME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: The manual for the Oracle **database** is here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/toc.htm not every page on "docs.oracle.com" is about the database. You are probably looking for `to_char()`

Comment: And I suggest to use correct tags. Your question is not about spring nor java

Comment: You're linking to documentation for Oracle Tuxedo, which is not Oracle database.

Comment: the link you are providing does not work!

Answer (score 0):

That particular function is not supported by the Oracle *Database*. I imagine your actual requirement is not to use `stftime()`, but to convert a date to a string. To do that in Oracle, you use `TO_CHAR`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html#GUID-0C3EEFD1-AE3D-452D-BF23-2FC95664E78F